# Inserting values at empty indexes in arrays. How can I write this code shorter or more modular?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following code I wrote which takes a 2d array with arrays of varying length and appends the value 0 to every index until all arrays are of the same length.

Can this code be written shorter or more efficient and modular?

```
a = [[1,7],[2,3],[5,1,2],[3],[1],[]]

l = a.map(&:length).max 
a2 = a.each{|e| e.push(Array.new(l - e.length, 0) )}
a2.each{|e| e.flatten!}

#=> [[1, 7, 0], [2, 3, 0], [5, 1, 2], [3, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

**UPDATE**

Because I feel unable to award an accepted answer to the two answers given thus far based on the simplicity of the written code itself, I have decided to award it based on the efficiency of the running speed of the code.

```
100 test cases running code block 10000 times.

#My Code:
#average run time of test case -> 0.24267sec
#standard deviation -> 0.00735sec

#Stefan’s Code:
#average run time of test case -> 0.06389sec
#standard deviation -> 0.00756sec

#steenslag’s Code:
#average run time of test case -> 0.0577sec
#standard deviation -> 0.00413sec
```

tests were conducted under the same conditions using a custom written ruby timer class I made and are only relative to each other and my crappy 2010-macbookpro on which I ran them.

Comment: I should mention that all answers were very helpful in answering my question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flatten` could be avoided by splatting the array:

```
l = a.max_by(&:size).size 
a2 = a.each{|e| e.push(*Array.new(l - e.length, 0) )}
```

Comment: `max` returns the maximum element, which could be `[20]`

Answer (score 5):

Another option using [`Array#fill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-fill):

```
l = a.map(&:length).max
a.each { |e| e.fill(0, e.length...l) }

a #=> [[1, 7, 0], [2, 3, 0], [5, 1, 2], [3, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I was trying this in irb.. keep getting error -- **RangeError: -1...3 out of range** :p

Comment: You always give the best.

Comment: Still don't know.. I was trying `a.each { |ary| ary.fill(0, (ary.size - 1)...max_length) }`

Comment: Humm.. Mine had little bit logical error.. But I got stuck into the **RangeError** one.. :(

Comment: @sawa humm `#fill` is the perfect sense for this.. I knew it.. But thanks Stefan also liked it.. +1

Answer (score 1):

One more way, four days late:

```
len = a.map(&:size).max
a.map { |e| Array.new(len) { |i| e[i].to_i } }
  #=> [[1,7,0],[2,3,0],[5,1,2],[3,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```